# Customize x and y values scale limit on Taylor diagram

Tags: r, diagram, taylor-series, plotrix

I have a problem with customizing the x and y values limit scale in Taylor diagram function from library(plotrix). On this image, I want to change the limit of x and y values to be 3.
[image]

```
taylor.diagram(ref=g1, model=b1, pos.cor=T,col=cols[1],pch=17,add=FALSE,main="",
                 cex.lab=2,
                 ylab="Standard Deviation (Normalised)",xlab="",
                 show.gamma=TRUE,ngamma=5,gamma.col="cadetblue1",sd.arcs=1,
                 ref.sd=TRUE,grad.corr.lines=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.95),
                 pcex=size_pch,cex.axis=2,normalize=TRUE,mar=c(5,6,5,10),
                 lwd=10,font=5,lty=2)
taylor.diagram(ref=g1, model=c1, pos.cor=T, col=cols[2], pch=17,add=TRUE,
                 xlab="Standard Deviation (Normalised)",
                 ylab="Standard Deviation (Normalised)",
                 show.gamma=TRUE,ngamma=5,gamma.col="cadetblue1",sd.arcs=1,
                 ref.sd=TRUE,grad.corr.lines=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.95),
                 pcex=size_pch,cex.axis=2,normalize=TRUE,mar=c(5,6,5,10),
                 lwd=10,font=5,lty=2)
```

If anyone know how to change the limit for x and y please help me. Im really appreciate for your help.
Thanks in advance.